# TypeError: obj[key].includes is not a function: in filter function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, filter

I would like find objects that have any propery with some value. But I have error: TypeError: obj[key].includes is not a function.
How to fix it?

```js
var aa = [{id: 1,type: 1,status: 1,name: 'txt'},{id: 2,type: 1,status: 1,name: 'txt'},{id: 3,type: 0,status: 0,name: 'txt'}];

function filterIt(arr, searchKey) {
  return arr.filter(function(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).some(function(key) {
      return obj[key].includes(searchKey);
    })
  });
}

filterIt(aa, 'txt');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Object.values` instead:

```js
var aa = [{id: 1,type: 1,status: 1,name: 'txt'},{id: 2,type: 1,status: 1,name: 'txt'},{id: 3,type: 0,status: 0,name: 'txt'}];

function filterIt(arr, searchKey) {
  return arr.filter(function(obj) {
    return Object.values(obj).includes(searchKey);
  });
}

console.log(filterIt(aa, 'txt'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

You can also make this code more compact:

```js
var aa = [{id: 1,type: 1,status: 1,name: 'txt'},{id: 2,type: 1,status: 1,name: 'txt'},{id: 3,type: 0,status: 0,name: 'txt'}];

const filterIt = (arr, searchKey) => arr.filter(obj => Object.values(obj).includes(searchKey));

console.log(filterIt(aa, 'txt'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the `Object.values` of the object to get an array of values, and then you can see if any values match the `searchKey` (though, you're searching for *values*, so probably better to name it `valueToFind`):

```js
var aa = [{
    id: 1,
    type: 1,
    status: 1,
    name: 'txt'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: 1,
    status: 1,
    name: 'txt',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    type: 0,
    status: 0,
    name: 'txt'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    type: 0,
    status: 0,
    name: 'wrongname'
  },
];

function filterIt(arr, valueToFind) {
  return arr.filter(function(obj) {
    return Object.values(obj).includes(valueToFind);
  });
}

console.log(filterIt(aa, 'txt'));
```

Because you were using `.some`, consider using ES6 syntax for more concise code:

```js
var aa = [{
    id: 1,
    type: 1,
    status: 1,
    name: 'txt'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: 1,
    status: 1,
    name: 'txt',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    type: 0,
    status: 0,
    name: 'txt'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    type: 0,
    status: 0,
    name: 'wrongname'
  },
];

const filterIt = (arr, valueToFind) => arr.filter(
  obj => Object.values(obj).includes(valueToFind)
);

console.log(filterIt(aa, 'txt'));
```